# How to substitute a table by li tags?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I just want to order some li tags the same way I would do with this code

```
<table>

<tr>
    <td colspan='2' rowspan='2'>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td>
    </td>

</tr>
```

For JQuery script reason, I can't use a table, only a list, but I want to display it just like it would have been with a table.

So, I don't know which of theses properties I have to use:

Inline-block,
Block,
Inline

Comment: `display: table-cell` to the rescue! This won't work for IE7 and older, but is [worth a look](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp).

Comment: are you specific on the rows and columns? or are they of no particular order?

Comment: You'd need `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell`. You're going to have a bit of trouble because the `<ul>` will be the table and your `<li>` would be table cells, but a list only has those two semantic elements so you're going to have to be creative to get them into separate table rows.

Comment: yeah, the row and col 2 for the first one is important, I don't know how displat table-cell would manage that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments mention: `display: table-cell` is the key. The layout you asked for should look something like

```
<ul style="display: table;">
  <li style="display: table-row;">
    <ul>
      <li style="display: table-cell;"></li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Comment: Great ! I'm gonna give a look at that, thanks, I let you know

Comment: Cool, I'm almost There BUT, how can I simulate rowspan and colspan = 2 ?

Comment: A real row-/colspan can not be done via css as it is a _structural_ (=html), no _layout_ (=css) issue. You could **a)** class the cells you want to 'combine' the same and do something like `.combined { border-collapse: collapse; border: 0px; }` or **b)** change the dimensions of the one big cell via css / javascript+css (but that is truly ugly, I know... )